# How to manage Typescript conditioning interfaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

I have a case when API returns 2 different types of history logs.

The interface for the operation was successful.

```
export interface IsyncSuccess { 
    deleted_count: number,
    new_count: number
}
```

And interface for operation failed

```
export interface IsyncFailed { 
    error_message: string
}
```

Interface for entire log.

```
export interface logType {
    type: "SYNC_SUCCESS" | "SYNC_FAILED" // for simplicity here are strings, normally its enum
    data: IsyncSuccess | IsyncFailed
}
```

And in table row I have conditioning like that

```
const HistoryTableRow: React.FC<{ log: logType }> = React.memo(({ log }) => {
    const getLog = () => {
        if (log.type === "SYNC_SUCCESS") {
            const data = log.data as IsyncSuccess
            return <>
                <Td>
                    {data.new_count}
                </Td>
                <Td>
                    {data.deleted_count}
                </Td>
            </>
        } else {
            const data = log.data as IsyncFailed
            return <>
                <Td colspan={2}>
                    {data.error_message}
                </Td>
            </>
        }
    }
    return (
        <TbodyTr>
            {getLog()}
        </TbodyTr>
    )
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => (true))
```

It works.
Is good practice conditioning interfaces? Is there more elegant solution for this case, when API returns different log types?

Comment: You could use a type guard instead, this would ensure that at runtime the object effectively matches the expected signature: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`discriminated union type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) may be more appropriate here as a way of combining your possible states in a way that will also give you type-safety/intellisense. For example:

```
export interface ISyncSuccess { 
    deleted_count: number,
    new_count: number
}
export interface ISyncFailed { 
    error_message: string
}

interface ILogTypeSuccess {
  type: "SYNC_SUCCESS"
  data: ISyncSuccess
}
interface ILogTypeError {
  type: "SYNC_ERROR"
  data: ISyncFailed
}
type LogType = ILogTypeSuccess | ILogTypeError
```

You can then use the `type` property to "discriminate" and infer what type the `data` property will be (with the original approach `data` would always be of type `ISyncSuccess | ISyncFailed` regardless of the type of `type`)

```
function checkLogType(logType: LogType) {
    if (logType.type === "SYNC_SUCCESS") {
        logType.data // ISyncSuccess
    }
    else {
        logType.data // ISyncError
    }
}

const validSuccess: LogType = {
    type: "SYNC_SUCCESS",
    data: {
        deleted_count: 0,
        new_count: 0,
    }
}
const invalidSuccess: LogType = {
    type: "SYNC_SUCCESS",
    data: {
        error_message: 'some message' // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'error_message' does not exist in type 'ISyncSuccess'.(2322)
    }
}
```

---

It is also easy to add new states in without losing that benefit, e.g.

```
interface ISyncLoading {
  loading_message: string;
}
interface ILogTypeLoading {
  type: "SYNC_LOADING"
  data: ISyncLoading
}
type LogType = ILogTypeSuccess | ILogTypeError | ILogTypeLoading

const validLoading: LogType = {
    type: "SYNC_LOADING",
    data: {
        loading_message: 'some message'
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQGUBPJbQgV21wGca4BvOAKDjbgBNgAbYVDgPrYIFFAC44SCgFsARmgA0rdkmAB3ISPGSZ8qMwC%20zUJFiIUaLLgIkyAMUwJeHRi3Zw0UaAOnA6mAHNgCRoYKGQAw2ZkVAwcPCJSbAAZCEwOCMZlbjSMpACfPxpA4LhQ8PyAbijoizjrfFSAgBViMGBKaiKsthg20oAiQgBNADkAYQFCAFVx8YBRQkIB5Q5MGEwJRLJO2hoomMt4gibW9vmoLygeuD72iSGxyfmAJReAeReVtjWNrdtsA4nMAOAc6lYEqd%20ql0pkGMo7oMRhMBMl3gBBAAi%20FGAHFvpx1psbEkYXlIkZEXAoe04ABeE4QFr9XbdAA%20jOZ50u0DgHMaTLOwDJEWYYvQomwMAQECQcGwAAtgNgANY04AAChyXNK6oAlDc2Ah0HAtYL%20gA6Kl0m1wR4omZzRbLA3w9zubVCi2-TBwAD0fpJOyoe2UbCM7h4NDwbvdbE9lp9-sD22wFyuYbgRiMzGESFCcAAbphuAgOKy6BJ1fTDbd%20g9kZNHQslgMlO4fRJY3GuLx%20JpRDAJAAGdtxyTqAfaUeZ7O52UF5DF0vlkNFKvm2kM7t1%2052xtTWYt5Zjn5EruZyM8qCFfxBCQAchoEF8cF8d%20AD%20TcHT0Ak71kAArZV4FLWISzfTBiDgWVuGgmh2mwY1oJVJAIDUOUwC8dpYAQPwFDgTAkBcB9PG8d9iiCL8OAgPxJAgeBQAQRc5SpB9UwrGgHwtDUACYAGZeN4vVZzYGoxTzAtlzLEV8g3HUax3REGyeVEMWxPE20zTtaw9XIIlvSjSifF88AokoH1nQwgA)